# Lifetime of static variable on windows service

Tags: wcf

I am wondering what would be the life time of a static variable in windows service. I have a windows service and static variable to save the messages flowing inside the service. will I get the messages saved on the static variable after the service is restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, static variables will revert to their original values upon application restart, and a service restart is an application restart.

Answer (score 0):

That answered - if you need a transient data store for messages, you might consider using Entity Framework 4.1 code first with a simple object structure to hold your messages.  The framework will create the data store for you safely and it will persist between executions.